# using declaration of a specialized variadic template class

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, using-statement

Is it possible to define `FloatType` in such a way that I can declare a `f1` as

```
FloatType f1;
```

instead of

```
FloatType<> f1;
```

If i try to use the former i get a

`error: use of class template 'FloatType' requires template arguments`

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Type
{
};

template <typename... Args>
class Type<float, Args...>
{
};

template <typename... Args>
using FloatType = Type<float, Args...>;

int
main(int, char **)
{
    FloatType<> f1;
    FloatType<float> f2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can but then there are template gurus more knowledgeable than me that might offer a solution.

Comment: You can't. You'll just have to make an alias for it:

   `using FloatTypeEmpty = FloatType<>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is impossible. From the standard §14.3/4, emphasis mine:

> When template argument packs or default *template-arguments* are used, a *template-argument* list can be
>   empty. In that case the empty `<>` brackets **shall still be used** as the *template-argument-list*. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
>   template <class T = char> class String;
>   String<>* p; // OK: String<char>
>   String* q;   // syntax error
>
>   template <class ... Elements> class Tuple;
>   Tuple<>* t; // OK: Elements is empty
>   Tuple* u;   // syntax error
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

But then, what's wrong with writing `FloatType<>`? If seeing the empty brackes really irks you, you can introduce another alias for them, but that kind of obfuscates things:

```
using DefFloatType = FloatType<>;
```

Plus, it's more typing!

Comment: thanks for the answer.  agreed `FloatType<>` is cleaner than the alias.